# Print each element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm practicing arrays, and I'm trying to print out each element of a list that the user inputs into the list. I'm having trouble at the last for- loop. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. *I'm learning java solo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the length of the array: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = input.nextInt(); 

    int[] arr; 
    arr = new int[length]; 


    //Asks the user to input values into a list
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
        System.out.println("Enter number into list: "); 
        int number = input.nextInt(); 

        arr[counter] = number;

    }//end of for-


    System.out.println("The list is below: ");
    System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Entry");

    //ERROR: This is where the error occurs!!!!!
    //Displays the list to the user 
    for (int count: arr){
        System.out.printf("%d%8d\n"
                , count, arr[count]);
    }//end of for- 
}//end of main method
```

EDIT: I fixed my code by adding a public count variable. Then calling that variable in the last for- loop, etc. If there is a better way PLS LMK!!

Comment: `ERROR: This is where the error occurs!!!!!` and the error is...?

Comment: @tnw Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 122
 at initarray.InitArray.main(InitArray.java:36) *(122 is the first number i inputted)

Comment: Yes that's because you aren't using the index of the array, but the value that you fill in with the `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//ERROR: This is where the error occurs!!!!!
//Displays the list to the user 
for (int count: arr){
    System.out.printf("%d%8d\n"
            , count, arr[count]);
}//end of for-
```

This is not correct. Say you have an array with the values `[1, 2, 300]`. The output you would get with your code would be:

- `1, 2`
- `2, 300`
- `Index error`

This is because you are calling `arr[count]`, in my example count would become `300`, so you will try to access index `300` in your array, it doesn't exist. What you are looking for is:

```
for(int index : arr) {
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

This will print out all of the elements in your `arr`. If you want to print out the index and then the corresponding value at that index you will need to do a regular for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I suspected that I can't show the index using the enhanced for loop. I'll upvote your answer

Comment: Unless you use another variable you're correct. The for-each loop is useful for when you want to access the data and don't care about the index number.

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop will iterate over the values, the index itself will be implicit and not accessible.

You probably want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length: arr++){
    System.out.printf("%d%8d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

... or if you want to use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (int value : arr){
    System.out.printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

... but then you will not have the index.

Comment: yeah, but I want to familiarize myself with the *for(x: array) form. Just to get better. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to change:

```
for (int count: arr){
    System.out.println(count);          
}
```

The count here actually displays the value that you put in the array.

So if you have entered 12, 13, 14 as your inputs, then this count will display 12, 13, and 14.

The length of the array is the first input that you take which is different than the array input.

To print the index you can do something like this:

```
int c =0;
for (int count: arr){
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(count);
    c++;
}
```

Comment: I did something similar, but thought there was a better way of showing it. I already favorited user123. Thank you though!